# Spring propery placeholder not working as expected if defined twice

Tags: spring

I have defined 2 property placeholder conf with same order .Behaviour what i was found is that if i define a property in the 2nd file with default value it is not picking from the file.if i didnot specify the default value it is taking from the file.can anybody help.``

1)

### config.properties

userName=Jithin
2)

## configtext.properties

charlength=256

### Program:

@Value("${charlength:128}")
private String charLenght; 
If i specify the default values as 128, charLenth field is assigned with 128
If i am not specifying the default value. ie: 
@Value("${charlength}")
private String charLenght;  In this case, it is reading from the property file and assigned with 256

Comment: Please try to make your post more clear.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the relevant parts of your configuration.